# Django - Forms, how to upload multiple files at a time on a form? Unable to get a ClearableInputField to have the "multiple: True" to work

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload, django-forms, django-file-upload

I am trying to allow my users to select multiple files when uploading file(s).  I am trying to allow the field on the forms.py file to have this functionality with the "multiple" property.  I have seen other examples found online, but it does not work for me.

```
forms.py", line 168, in Meta
    "image": ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple": True}),
  File "/x/x/x/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 393, in __init__
    % self.__class__.__qualname__
ValueError: ClearableFileInput doesn't support uploading multiple files.
```

```
pip list
Package           Version
----------------- -------
asgiref           3.4.1
Django            3.2.21
django-auth-ldap  4.0.0
django-filter     21.1
lxml              4.9.3
mysqlclient       2.1.1
Pillow            8.4.0
pip               21.3.1
pyasn1            0.5.0
pyasn1-modules    0.3.0
python-docx       0.8.11
python-ldap       3.4.3
pytz              2023.3
setuptools        39.2.0
sqlparse          0.4.4
typing_extensions 4.1.1
```

```
forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, Select, ClearableFileInput
class UploadImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = [
            "image",
            "description"
        ]
        labels = {
            "image": ("Image"),
            "description": ("Description")
        }
        widgets = {
            "image": ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple": True}),
        }
```

```
models.py
class Images(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True)
    test_part_id = models.ForeignKey('TestParts', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'images'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.image}"
```

```
views.py
def testing(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and "fileForm" in request.POST:
        imageForm = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if imageForm.is_valid():
            for image in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
                new_image = Images(image=image)
                new_image.save()

            return redirect(fa_details, id=id)
```

I've included the view, but I don't think there is anything wrong in it that would prevent me from handling multiple files.  I manually created a form in the HTML/template and I am able to process multiple images and save into the database with no problems.  I could go this route, but something tells me it is not the recommended route.

I have even tried the official Django documentation, overriding the field in the form class instead of using the meta class(below).  It throws the same error.

```
file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

Comment: Found another way to fix the issue in this GitHub repo:  https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload/tree/master